# iOS swift convert mp3 to aac

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm converting an **mp3** to **m4a** in Swift with code based on [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_Export.html).

It works when I generate a PCM file. When I change the export format to m4a it generates a file but it won't play. Why is it corrupt?

Here is the code so far:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var rwAudioSerializationQueue:dispatch_queue_t!

    var asset:AVAsset!

    var assetReader:AVAssetReader!

    var assetReaderAudioOutput:AVAssetReaderTrackOutput!

    var assetWriter:AVAssetWriter!

    var assetWriterAudioInput:AVAssetWriterInput!

    var outputURL:NSURL!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let rwAudioSerializationQueueDescription = String(self) + " rw audio serialization queue"

        // Create the serialization queue to use for reading and writing the audio data.
        self.rwAudioSerializationQueue = dispatch_queue_create(rwAudioSerializationQueueDescription, nil)

        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsPath = paths[0]

        print(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("input", ofType: "mp3"))

        self.asset = AVAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("input", ofType: "mp3")! ))

        self.outputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath + "/output.m4a")

        print(self.outputURL)

      //  [self.asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"tracks"] completionHandler:^{

        self.asset.loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys(["tracks"], completionHandler: {

            print("loaded")

            var success = true
            var localError:NSError?

            success = (self.asset.statusOfValueForKey("tracks", error: &localError) == AVKeyValueStatus.Loaded)

            // Check for success of loading the assets tracks.
            //success = ([self.asset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&localError] == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded);
            if (success)
            {
                // If the tracks loaded successfully, make sure that no file exists at the output path for the asset writer.

                let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
                let localOutputPath = self.outputURL.path
                if (fm.fileExistsAtPath(localOutputPath!)) {
                    do {
                        try fm.removeItemAtPath(localOutputPath!)
                        success = true
                    } catch {

                    }
                }
            }
            if (success) {
                success = self.setupAssetReaderAndAssetWriter()
            }
            if (success) {
                success = self.startAssetReaderAndWriter()
            }
        })
    }

    func setupAssetReaderAndAssetWriter() -> Bool {

        do {
            try self.assetReader = AVAssetReader(asset: self.asset)
        } catch {

        }

        do {
            try self.assetWriter = AVAssetWriter(URL: self.outputURL, fileType: AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat)
        } catch {

        }

        var assetAudioTrack:AVAssetTrack? = nil
        let audioTracks = self.asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)

        if (audioTracks.count > 0) {
            assetAudioTrack = audioTracks[0]
        }

        if (assetAudioTrack != nil)
        {
            let decompressionAudioSettings:[String : AnyObject] = [
                AVFormatIDKey:Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM)
            ]

            self.assetReaderAudioOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: assetAudioTrack!, outputSettings: decompressionAudioSettings)

            self.assetReader.addOutput(self.assetReaderAudioOutput)

            var channelLayout = AudioChannelLayout()
            memset(&channelLayout, 0, sizeof(AudioChannelLayout));
            channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;

            /*let compressionAudioSettings:[String : AnyObject] = [
                AVFormatIDKey:Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC) ,
                AVEncoderBitRateKey:128000,
                AVSampleRateKey:44100 ,
               // AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey:16,
               // AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.High.rawValue,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey:2,
                AVChannelLayoutKey: NSData(bytes:&channelLayout, length:sizeof(AudioChannelLayout))
            ]

            var outputSettings:[String : AnyObject] = [
                AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
                AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                AVChannelLayoutKey: NSData(bytes:&channelLayout, length:sizeof(AudioChannelLayout)),
                AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
                AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: false,
                AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
                AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false
            ]*/

            let outputSettings:[String : AnyObject] = [
                AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                AVChannelLayoutKey: NSData(bytes:&channelLayout, length:sizeof(AudioChannelLayout))            ]

            self.assetWriterAudioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, outputSettings: outputSettings)

            self.assetWriter.addInput(self.assetWriterAudioInput)
        }

        return true
    }

    func startAssetReaderAndWriter() -> Bool {

        self.assetWriter.startWriting()

        self.assetReader.startReading()

        self.assetWriter.startSessionAtSourceTime(kCMTimeZero)

        self.assetWriterAudioInput.requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue(self.rwAudioSerializationQueue, usingBlock: {

            while (self.assetWriterAudioInput.readyForMoreMediaData ) {

                var sampleBuffer = self.assetReaderAudioOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()

                if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                    self.assetWriterAudioInput.appendSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer!)

                    sampleBuffer = nil

                } else {
                    self.assetWriterAudioInput.markAsFinished()
                    self.assetReader.cancelReading()
                    print("done")
                   break
                }
            }
        })

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: "`sizeof(AudioChannelLayout)`"..... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*update*

You're creating a `caf` file instead of an `m4a`.

Replace `AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat` with `AVFileTypeAppleM4A` in

```
AVAssetWriter(URL: self.outputURL, fileType: AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat)
```

Call `self.assetWriter.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler()` when you've finished.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that hasn't worked. The completion handler is firing but the file is still corrupt.

Comment: can you provide a link to the file?

Comment: ah ha. Thanks. Thats done it. One last question is that i want to split the left and right channels into seperate files.. am I best to use two asset writers for this?

Comment: if this answer solves your problem, please accept it - then start a new question for your next problem

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Updated the source code in the question to Swift 4 and wrapped it in a class. Credit goes to **Castles** and **Rythmic Fistman** for original source code and answer. Left author's comments, added a few assertion's and print statements for debugging. Tested on iOS.

The bit rate for the output file is hardcoded at 96kb/s, you can easily override this value. Most of the audio files I'm converting are 320kb/s, so I'm using this class to compress the files for offline storage. Compression results at the bottom of this answer.

Usage:

```
let inputFilePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/file.mp3")
let outputFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/output/compressed.mp4")

if let audioConverter = AVAudioFileConverter(inputFileURL: inputFilePath, outputFileURL: outputFileURL) {
    audioConverter.convert()
}
```

Class

```
import AVFoundation

final class AVAudioFileConverter {

  var rwAudioSerializationQueue: DispatchQueue!
  var asset:AVAsset!
  var assetReader:AVAssetReader!
  var assetReaderAudioOutput:AVAssetReaderTrackOutput!
  var assetWriter:AVAssetWriter!
  var assetWriterAudioInput:AVAssetWriterInput!
  var outputURL:URL
  var inputURL:URL

  init?(inputFileURL: URL, outputFileURL: URL) {
    inputURL = inputFileURL
    outputURL = outputFileURL

    if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: inputURL.absoluteString)) {
      print("Input file does not exist at file path \(inputURL.absoluteString)")
      return nil
    }
  }

  func convert() {
    let rwAudioSerializationQueueDescription = " rw audio serialization queue"
    // Create the serialization queue to use for reading and writing the audio data.
    rwAudioSerializationQueue = DispatchQueue(label: rwAudioSerializationQueueDescription)
    assert(rwAudioSerializationQueue != nil, "Failed to initialize Dispatch Queue")

    asset = AVAsset(url: inputURL)
    assert(asset != nil, "Error creating AVAsset from input URL")
    print("Output file path -> ", outputURL.absoluteString)

    asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["tracks"], completionHandler: {
      var success = true
      var localError:NSError?
      success = (self.asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "tracks", error: &localError) == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded)
      // Check for success of loading the assets tracks.
      if (success) {
        // If the tracks loaded successfully, make sure that no file exists at the output path for the asset writer.
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let localOutputPath = self.outputURL.path
        if (fm.fileExists(atPath: localOutputPath)) {
          do {
            try fm.removeItem(atPath: localOutputPath)
            success = true
          } catch {
            print("Error trying to remove output file at path -> \(localOutputPath)")
          }
        }
      }

      if (success) {
        success = self.setupAssetReaderAndAssetWriter()
      } else {
        print("Failed setting up Asset Reader and Writer")
      }
      if (success) {
        success = self.startAssetReaderAndWriter()
        return
      } else {
        print("Failed to start Asset Reader and Writer")
      }

    })
  }

  func setupAssetReaderAndAssetWriter() -> Bool {
    do {
      assetReader = try AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
    } catch {
      print("Error Creating AVAssetReader")
    }

    do {
      assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: outputURL, fileType: AVFileType.m4a)
    } catch {
      print("Error Creating AVAssetWriter")
    }

    var assetAudioTrack:AVAssetTrack? = nil
    let audioTracks = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)

    if (audioTracks.count > 0) {
      assetAudioTrack = audioTracks[0]
    }

    if (assetAudioTrack != nil) {

      let decompressionAudioSettings:[String : Any] = [
        AVFormatIDKey:Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM)
      ]

      assetReaderAudioOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: assetAudioTrack!, outputSettings: decompressionAudioSettings)
      assert(assetReaderAudioOutput != nil, "Failed to initialize AVAssetReaderTrackOutout")
      assetReader.add(assetReaderAudioOutput)

      var channelLayout = AudioChannelLayout()
      memset(&channelLayout, 0, MemoryLayout<AudioChannelLayout>.size);
      channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;

      let outputSettings:[String : Any] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey: 96000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVChannelLayoutKey: NSData(bytes:&channelLayout, length:MemoryLayout<AudioChannelLayout>.size)]

      assetWriterAudioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.audio, outputSettings: outputSettings)
      assert(rwAudioSerializationQueue != nil, "Failed to initialize AVAssetWriterInput")
      assetWriter.add(assetWriterAudioInput)

    }
    print("Finsihed Setup of AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter")
    return true
  }

  func startAssetReaderAndWriter() -> Bool {
    print("STARTING ASSET WRITER")
    assetWriter.startWriting()
    assetReader.startReading()
    assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: kCMTimeZero)

    assetWriterAudioInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: rwAudioSerializationQueue, using: {

      while(self.assetWriterAudioInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData ) {
        var sampleBuffer = self.assetReaderAudioOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
        if(sampleBuffer != nil) {
          self.assetWriterAudioInput.append(sampleBuffer!)
          sampleBuffer = nil
        } else {
          self.assetWriterAudioInput.markAsFinished()
          self.assetReader.cancelReading()
          self.assetWriter.finishWriting {
            print("Asset Writer Finished Writing")
          }
          break
        }
      }
    })
    return true
  }
}
```

Input File: 17.3 MB

```
// generated with afinfo on mac
File:           D290A73C37B777F1.mp3
File type ID:   MPG3
Num Tracks:     1
----
Data format:     2 ch,  44100 Hz, '.mp3' (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1152 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame
                no channel layout.
estimated duration: 424.542025 sec
audio bytes: 16981681
audio packets: 16252
bit rate: 320000 bits per second
packet size upper bound: 1052
maximum packet size: 1045
audio data file offset: 322431
optimized
audio 18720450 valid frames + 576 priming + 1278 remainder = 18722304
----
```

Output File: 5.1 MB

```
// generated with afinfo on Mac
File:           compressed.m4a
File type ID:   m4af
Num Tracks:     1
----
Data format:     2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'aac ' (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1024 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame
Channel layout: Stereo (L R)
estimated duration: 424.542041 sec
audio bytes: 5019294
audio packets: 18286
bit rate: 94569 bits per second
packet size upper bound: 763
maximum packet size: 763
audio data file offset: 44
not optimized
audio 18722304 valid frames + 2112 priming + 448 remainder = 18724864
format list:
[ 0] format:    2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'aac ' (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1024 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame
Channel layout: Stereo (L R)
----
```